# Selenium RC stuck at Checking Resource aliases

Tags: firefox, selenium, debian, regression-testing, xvfb

I am trying to use Selenium RC to run regression tests on a website. I created a test suite using the Selenium IDE tool and 3 tests associated with it. These tests run successfully within the IDE but when I try to run them using Selenium server, I always get stuck at "Checking Resource aliases"

I'm using the following command:

```
java -jar /home/adam/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -htmlSuite *firefox /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin http://devwebsite.com /root/selenium/tests/suite.html /root/selenium/results.html -firefoxProfileTemplate /root/.mozilla/firefox/9r0afiwh.profile -log debug.log
```

Last few lines of output where it gets stuck:

```
INFO: Launching a standalone server
13:51:10.594 INFO - Writing debug logs to debug.log
13:51:10.595 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 14.0-b16
13:51:10.596 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.32-5-686 i386
13:51:10.603 INFO - v2.31.0, with Core v2.31.0. Built from revision 1bd294d
13:51:10.711 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
13:51:10.712 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
13:51:10.714 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
13:51:10.715 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
13:51:10.715 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
13:51:46.397 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@867e89
13:51:46.398 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
13:51:46.408 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
13:51:46.408 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@86f241
jar:file:/home/adam/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
13:51:46.508 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
13:51:48.019 INFO - Launching Firefox...
13:51:48.739 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
```

Everything seems to work right up to the point where it actually runs the tests. Researching around showed problems with people using "Test Case" instead of "Test Suite" when naming the test suite in HTML, which I'm not doing. I also removed the XML line in the test suite file to see if it would matter. I'm not using a proxy as another user here had an issue with this error.

This is all running on a headless Debian server. There are numerous guides for demonstrating how to set this up using Xvfb. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't figure out what.

Comment: This still isn't working under Linux, but I had a similar problem getting stuck at Checking Resource aliases on my Windows machine that was solved by ensuring file extensions for test cases AND suites were .html. This allowed the test to run to completion and generate the results.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the selenium webdriver. That may be an alternative to the RC client if you have something to kick off the scripts.

Comment: I used the Selenium Server because it supports the HTMLSuite, which allows you to run tests defined in the Selenium IDE. It's much easier and quicker to use. I tried the webdriver and it works well but requires more time to create test cases.